# Common breaks and free axes for overlapping lattice histograms

Tags: r, plot, histogram, lattice

What is the required incantation to achieve an overlapping, faceted `lattice::histogram` with common break points (across groups, but potentially varying across panels)?

For example, assume I want the total range of the data (groups combined) for each panel to be split into 30 bins.

#### Example data:

```r
library(lattice)
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(v1=rep(c('A', 'B'), each=1000), 
                v2=rep(c(0.5, 1), each=2000),
                mean=rep(c(0, 10, 2, 12), each=1000))
d$x <- rnorm(nrow(d), d$mean, d$v2)
```

#### Using `nint=30`?

```r
p1 <- histogram(~x|v1, d, groups=v2, nint=30,
                scales=list(relation='free'), type='percent',
                panel = function(...) {
                  panel.superpose(..., panel.groups=panel.histogram, 
                                  col=c('red', 'blue'), alpha=0.3)
                })
p1
```

[image]

Above, the bins are consistent across groups, but (1) the x-axis limits are shared across panels (problematic when the x-axis range varies substantially across panels - I really want the 30 bins to be calculated individually for each panel), and (2) the y-axis is cramped when using `type='percent'` (it should extend further).

#### Using `breaks=30`?

```r
p2 <- histogram(~x|v1, d, groups=v2, breaks=30,
                scales=list(relation='free'), type='percent',
                panel = function(...) {
                  panel.superpose(..., panel.groups=panel.histogram, 
                                  col=c('red', 'blue'), alpha=0.3)
                })
p2
```

[image]

Now the axis limits look good, but the bins width varies across groups.

#### So...

Using `lattice`, how can I achieve overlapping, faceted histograms that have constant bin width across groups within panels, but have axis limits that fit the data for each panel?

(I realise that ggplot is an option, but I want the figure style to be consistent with my other lattice plots.)

Comment: Try using `nint=30` rather than `breaks=30`. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick - I think my post needed a tl;dr, but I do show `nint=30` above. Problem is that it doesn't seem to respect `relation='free'` for the x-axis, and I'd like to extend the y limits (though using type='count' resolves the latter, and I could relabel the axis ticks if I do that).

Comment: A partial solution is https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/028106a8b82dc27937ec9bb6de01da8e, but (as per my comment there) it won't work well if the range of values (x-axis) varies greatly across panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but I'm afraid it's rather pedestrian. At least it only requires the trellis object itself; it will assume the number of bins you want in each panel is equal to the *nint* parameter.

It works like this: check whether the panels ranges overlap. If they don't, split each (slightly extended) range into `nint` bins, then concatenate them with a few empty bins in between. We also need to work out the y range, which we do by scaling according to the maximum number of counts.

```r
fix_facets <- function(p1)
{
  n_bins <- p1$panel.args.common$nint
  xvals1 <- p1$panel.args[[1]]$x
  xvals2 <- p1$panel.args[[2]]$x

  if(min(xvals2) > max(xvals1) | min(xvals1) > max(xvals2)){
    left_range  <- range(xvals1)
    left_range  <- left_range + (diff(left_range) * c(-0.1, 0.1))
    left_bins   <- seq(left_range[1], left_range[2], diff(left_range)/n_bins)
    right_range <- range(xvals2)
    right_range  <- right_range + (diff(right_range) * c(-0.1, 0.1))
    right_bins   <- seq(right_range[1], right_range[2], diff(right_range)/n_bins)

    if(max(left_range) < min(right_range)){
      mid_bins <- seq(max(left_bins), min(right_bins), diff(left_bins[1:2]))
      all_bins <- c(left_bins, mid_bins, right_bins)
    } else {
      mid_bins <- seq(max(right_bins), min(left_bins), diff(right_bins[1:2]))
      all_bins <- c(right_bins, mid_bins, left_bins)
    }
    p1$panel.args.common$breaks <- all_bins
    p1$x.limits[[1]] <- left_range
    p1$x.limits[[2]] <- right_range
    histleft  <- hist(xvals1, breaks = left_bins)
    histright <- hist(xvals2, breaks = right_bins)
    group_factor <- 100 * length(p1$condlevels[[1]])

    p1$y.limits[[1]][2] <- group_factor * max(histleft$counts) / length(xvals1)
    p1$y.limits[[2]][2] <- group_factor * max(histright$counts) / length(xvals2)
  }
  return(p1)
}
```

So with your example, we can do this:

```
p1 <- histogram(~x|v1, d, groups=v2, nint=30,
                scales=list(relation='free'), type='percent',
                panel = function(...) {
                  panel.superpose(..., panel.groups=panel.histogram, 
                                  col=c('red', 'blue'), alpha=0.3)
                })
fix_facets(p1)
```

[image]

and to show it works with other numbers of bins...

```r
p1 <- histogram(~x|v1, d, groups=v2, nint=10,
                scales=list(relation='free'), type='percent',
                panel = function(...) {
                  panel.superpose(..., panel.groups=panel.histogram, 
                                  col=c('red', 'blue'), alpha=0.3)
                })
fix_facets(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: Pedestrian is fine - this looks great. I like that it updates the existing object.